# Install MacOS 10.12.2 on VMWare Fusion 8.5.3

Tags: macos, vmware

I have a MacBook Pro running MacOS 10.12.2.
It has VMWare Fusion 8.5.3.
I have downloaded `Install macOS Sierra` into the /Applications folder.

How do I install macOS 10.12.2 into VMWare Fusion.

I tried Google but there are so many references to overcoming issues with the beta versions of Sierra that I cannot find instructions that look as simple as this should be.

I tried the normal way of creating a new image in Fusion, but I get an error about choosing a startup disk.

1. File->New ...
2. Create a custom virtual machine
3. MacOS 10.12
4. Create a new virtual disk
5. Finish
6. Observe that it boots to blue screen and gives error about choosing startup disk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description here: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2056603 is still valid - which also has a small video of the installation process.

1. Select File > New from the Fusion menu bar.
2. Select "Install from disc or image" and Click Continue.
3. Drag and drop the Install MacOS Sierra application into Use operating system installation disc or image dialog box.
4. Click Continue.
5. Fusion should automatically discover the Guest Operating System. If not, ensure that the Operating System is set to Apple Mac OS X and that the version is set to Mac OS X 10.12.x. Click Continue.
6. If you want to modify any of the settings, such as memory (RAM), CPU, or hard disk size, click Customize Settings and specify the non-default values.
7. Click Finish. The installation starts.
8. When prompted, select Reinstall Mac OS X and click Continue.
9. Click Continue.
10. Agree to the license agreement and follow the prompts to begin the
     installation.

Comment: Ignoring that these instructions are for Mavericks and not for Sierra, I gave them a try.  They fail at step 5: "Unable to create the installation medium".

Comment: Did you ensure that is was the correct OS params for Sierra ??

Comment: I clicked continue.  I googled a bit and there was a suggestion to reboot.  That worked.  it is installing now.  As soon as the install is successful I will accept your answer.  I hate rebooting as a means to solve a problem on a mac; but it worked.

Comment: I was fooled by the VMWare UI.  I did not notice the "Install from disk or image" option on the UI because it is not in the list of alternative options.  It is just one big button.  I took the alternative options as the complete set of options.

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way to create a Sierra virtual machine with VMware Fusion 8 is to use the Recovery Partition as the source.

1. File -> New
2. Click on "Install OS X from the Recovery Partition"
3. Save the virtual disk image.
4. Click Finish to create the VM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you very much :D